scraping lyrics data from genius
Trying to get lyrics from the Genius API.
Here's a bit of my code. First I get data on artists (need to get their "id" from what I undestood)
# Set the Genius API token
Sys.setenv(GENIUS_API_TOKEN = 'TOKEN_HERE')

artists_names <- c("Taylor Swift", "One Republic", "Imagine Dragons")
# Define a function to search for artist data
fetch_artist_data <- function(artist_name) {
  artist_data <- tryCatch({
    search_genius_artist(artist_name)
  }, error = function(e) {
    # Return NA if there is an error
    return(NA)
  })
  return(artist_data)
}

# Plan for parallel processing
plan(multisession, workers = availableCores())

# Use future_lapply to fetch artist data in parallel
artist_data_list <- future_lapply(artists_names , fetch_artist_data)

# Combine the results into a data.table
combined_artist_data <- rbindlist(lapply(artist_data_list, as.data.table), fill = TRUE)

# Merge with original data to get correct artists
merged_data <- merge(combined_artist_data, artists_names, by = "name", all.y = TRUE)

# Select only the required columns
final_data <- merged_data[, .(id, name)]

final_data <- unique(final_data)
final_data <- final_data[complete.cases(final_data),]


This bit of code works fine, but now I neede to get the lyrics of as many songs from each of these artists as possible.
For that, I have
# Define a function to fetch song data for each artist
fetch_songs <- function(artist_id) {
  songs_data <- tryCatch({
    search_genius_songs(artist_id)
  }, error = function(e) {
    return(NA)
  })
  return(songs_data)
}

# Fetch songs for each artist in parallel
songs_list <- future_lapply(final_data$id, fetch_songs)

# Combine the song data into a data.table
combined_songs_data <- rbindlist(lapply(songs_list, as.data.table), fill = TRUE)

# Save songs data
write.csv(combined_songs_data, "songs_data.csv")

# Define a function to fetch lyrics for each song
fetch_lyrics <- function(song_id) {
  lyrics <- tryCatch({
    get_genius_lyrics(song_id)
  }, error = function(e) {
    return(NA)
  })
  return(lyrics)
}

# Fetch lyrics for each song in parallel
lyrics_list <- future_lapply(combined_songs_data$id, fetch_lyrics)

# Combine the lyrics data into a data.table
combined_lyrics_data <- rbindlist(lapply(lyrics_list, as.data.table), fill = TRUE)



But returns all nulls...
> head(songs_list)
[[1]]
[1] NA

[[2]]
[1] NA

[[3]]
[1] NA

[[4]]
[1] NA

[[5]]
[1] NA

[[6]]
[1] NA


Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

It will be much easier to answer your question if you can provide a minimal, reprodubile example. See if you can reproduce the error with just one artist, and share that example so that we can reproduce your problem on our machines.

should work now!

Please do not repost questions that you have essentially already asked. Instead, edit your existing question. This is a much better version of your original question by the way, so well done!
